# Regex: match values of php array (multiline) which are not quoted

Tags: php, regex

I try to match all array values of a PHP array - which are not quoted, but it has a multiline value (options) that is not working correctly.

My array is that:

```
[
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
]
```

That is the regex: `=>\s+([^'].*[^'][\s\S]+?)(\]\)\ \:\ \[\]|),\n`

Here is my test: https://regex101.com/r/gWWx7y/1

An alternative is to preprocess the array with another regex to remove all unneeded newlines, except the newlines which are in line with (=> and a line-end with `,`) but I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Just: don't. Yes, it is possible but why should anyone want to rely on such an algorithm?

Comment: If you insist: [`(?:=>\s*(?:\[|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|=>\s*\K.+`](https://regex101.com/r/2XmSQ6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
(?:=>\s*(?:\[|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|=>\s*\K.+
```

---

Broken down, this reads:

```
(?:                # non-capturing group
    =>\s*          # => plus whitespace, eventually
    (?:            # another non-capturing group
        \[         # a "[" literally
        |          # or
        '[^']*'    # some quoted string
    )
    (*SKIP)(*FAIL) # ignore all of the above
 )
 |                 # or
 =>\s*\K.+         # possibly unquoted things
```

But I'd never use it in any productive system. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2XmSQ6/1).

Comment: Thanks - but it not working correctly for the "options" part ...
I know that is not a good solution, but I see no other way - I like to patch the Laravel config files automatically in a docker image and laravel has only php arrays - i need to merge the arrays. I grab the orginal array as string from the file, but I can't parse it directly to a php array, because it has some helper functions inside - so I like to escape these functions for the merge and after i convert these back to the original.